# Create Oracle Materialized View to be refreshed every 5 minute Using materialized view log

Tags: sql, oracle, view, replication, materialized

I'm Trying to create Materialized View which will be updated every 5 minute automatically, I need update based on Mview log table.

I have created Materialized view log on TABLE1 [TABLE1.SQL Script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GD_P55XeZ5QzBmUTZqZ0k3dTQ/view)

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TABLE1;   -- MLOG$_TABLE1
```

Then I've created Materialized View

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW JIBO_MVIEW 
REFRESH START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE +5/24/60 
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
      SELECT O.ID
            ,O.DATETIME_CREATED
            ,O.ORIGINATOR
            ,O.DETAILS
            ,O.PAYMENT_REF
        FROM TABLE1 O
       WHERE O.ORIGINATOR LIKE '53%';
```

after changing some value In TABLE1, new Record is inserted MLOG$_TABLE1 log table

[image]

but changed value is not updated in Materialized view (JIBO_MVIEW). (even after one day :) )

As I checked in Alert Log there is problem with auto generated DBMS_JOB, it fails on every executions.

```
 - ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 4263
 - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 689
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195 - 
 - ORA-06512: at line 1
```

but if I execute job manually it works just fine. Here is code example

```
BEGIN DBMS_REFRESH.REFRESH('"JIBO"."JIBO_MVIEW"');
COMMIT;
END;
```

Then I have added new grants to user

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO JIBO; 
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO JIBO WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO JIBO;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA1.MLOG$_TABLE1 TO JIBO WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA1.TABLE1 TO JIBO WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and now I am getting this error while job executes automatically

```
 - ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 4287
 - ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 689
 - ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195
 - ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Please, helm me to solve this issue.
is this problem due to incorrectly created Materialized view, or maybe it's due to some parameter in oracle which should be turned on?

Comment: At first site everything is ok, maybe changed record doesn't meet  `WHERE O.ORIGINATOR LIKE '53%'` condition.

Comment: I have record in Materialized view (JIBO_MVIEW) but it does not changes after changing value in source table (TABLE1) for this record.

Comment: Do you see now the record in  MLOG$_TABLE1 ?

Comment: yes, the record which i have attached as a picture to my question is still there.

Comment: I'd like to know is the problem solved?

Comment: Your example works for me.  But I had to fill in some details about the original table and values.  It might help to create a fully reproducible test case so we can completely recreate all details.  Also, what happens when you try to manually refresh the job with code like this: `begin
 dbms_refresh.refresh(user||'."JIBO_MVIEW"');
end;
/`?

Comment: As I see problem didn't solve, maybe there is a problem with access rights. Try to create public synonim for MV and log table.

Comment: What is your Oracle version?
Does the issue reproduce in an empty schema with the table and mview only?

Comment: @JonHeller  Manual Update worked but automatic job does not works. what could be a reason? Maybe job could not make commit or something like this?

Comment: @BSamedi  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: This question could still benefit from a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Comment: I have shown Compilable example in my question, materialized view works but as it seems DBMS_JOB has problems while execution. i have added grant scrips also in question window

Comment: script for creating TABLE1 is missing

Comment: @BSamedi I've added a link of TABLE1 script in question form

Comment: I cannot see the grants for the materialized view itself, have you tried that too?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure but problem may be in refresh job creation for MV. 
try this queries.

`select * from user_jobs where what like 'dbms_refresh.refresh%';` what is the value of `BROKEN` column?

`select * from user_snapshot_refresh_times;`
and see this
`select * from V$PARAMETER where name = 'job_queue_processes'`  parameter value, is it ok, not exceeded.

Comment: job is broken due to failures (16), I've recreated the materialized view, did not change anything in source table(TABLE1), but  job still fails. which parameter should i check in V$PARAMETER view?

Comment: How many user jobs you have, maybe problem in jobs count, they are trying to exceed the value of `job_queue_processes` then you add one more?

Comment: I have only this job for my user, but in database there is many other job. result of `select * from V$PARAMETER where name = 'job_queue_processes'` query -------- > NUM 1872, NAME job_queue_processes, VALUE 20, DISPLAY_VALUE 20,ISDEFAULT FALSE,ISSES_MODIFIABLE FALSE,ISSYS_MODIFIABLE IMMEDIATE, ISINSTANCE_MODIFIABLE TRUE,ISMODIFIED FALSE,ISADJUSTED FALSE,ISDEPRECATED FALSE, ISBASIC FALSE, DESCRIPTION maximum number of job queue slave processes, UPDATE_COMMENT  ,HASH 1663833312

Comment: I think problem in this parameter, `job_queue_processes` as I know is common for all users jobs, so you have only 20 jobs to run for your oracle instance, try to increase `alter system set job_queue_processes = 1000`. And then recreate your view.

Comment: i have increased the limit, then create mview again, but job still fails.

Comment: Try to restart database, referring to oracle docs they say some parameters take effect after restart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141621/discussion-between-seyran-and-jibo).

Answer (score 2):

You can have Oracle manage the refresh job on it's own by creating a refresh group as follows

```
exec DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE(name => 'MY_RG', list => 'JIBO_MVIEW', next_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, interval => 'SYSTIMESTAMP + Interval ''5'' minute');
```

After that you can check the status of the refresh group using

```
select * from user_refresh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here are some general hints that might help you solving your permissions problem (table or view does not exist).

grant create any table, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW to MV_USER
where MV_USER is the OWNER of the MATERIALIZED VIEW.

Connect as that same MV_USER.

Then do your CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW.

To fix your broken jobs, connect as the MV_USER (owner of the MV).

Then run:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000                                         
declare                                                                  
v_mview VARCHAR2(30);                                                    
v_run   VARCHAR2(100);                                                
v_job number;                                                            
cursor user_mviews_c is                                                  
select mview_name from user_mviews ;                                     
cursor user_jobs_c is                                                    
select job from user_jobs ;                                              
begin                                                                    
open user_mviews_c;                                                      
loop                                                                     
   fetch user_mviews_c into v_mview;                                     
   exit when user_mviews_c%notfound;                                     
   v_run := 'exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH ('''||v_mview||''',''C'');';        
   dbms_output.put_line(v_run);                                          
end loop;                                                                
close user_mviews_c;                                                     
open user_jobs_c;                                                        
loop                                                                     
   fetch user_jobs_c into v_job;                                         
   exit when user_jobs_c%notfound;                                       
   v_run := 'exec DBMS_JOB.RUN ('||v_job||');';                          
   dbms_output.put_line(v_run);                                          
end loop;                                                                
close user_jobs_c;                                                       
end;                                                                     
/
```

Comment: It doesn't helped.

Comment: do you still get ORA-00942?

Comment: no now i have another error: `ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 4287
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 689
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195
ORA-06512: at line 1
`

Comment: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: Grants I have added by SYS user on my MV user: `GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO JIBO;
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO JIBO WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO JIBO;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA1.MLOG$_EBPP_PAYMENTS TO JIBO WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON RTPSEBPP.EBPP_PAYMENTS TO UFC_DAVITJ WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Answer (score 0):

In a similar setup I have grant execute to all the `sys` objects below.  Maybe this will solve your problem.

```
DBMS_DEFER_SYS,  
DBMS_SNAPSHOT,  
DBMS_SNAP_REPAPI,  
DBMS_REPCAT_DECL,  
DBMS_DEFER_QUERY,  
DBMS_REPCAT_UTL,  
DBMS_DEFER_INTERNAL_QUERY,  
DBMS_DEFER_INTERNAL_SYS,  
DBMS_REPCAT_UNTRUSTED,  
DBMS_OFFLINE_SNAPSHOT,  
DBMS_REPCAT,  
DBMS_INTERNAL_REPCAT,  
DBMS_REPCAT_RPC,  
DBMS_RECTIFIER_DIFF,  
DBMSOBJGWRAPPER,  
DBMS_REPCAT_RGT,  
DBMS_OFFLINE_OG
```